# Only Include a Criteria if There are Multiple Matches

Tags: sql, join, left-join, case

I'm trying to get the pID from the merged_products table, and there are many cases where the Thickness, Width, Grade and Length match a dozen or more records and the only difference is that ONE of them will contain the AID.

I only need to the include the AID when there are more than one matches, but I do not know how to make that happen.

```
CREATE TABLE #raw_customer (
    [DECIMAL] decimal(20, 4),
    [WIDTH] decimal(20, 4),
    [LENGTH] decimal(20, 4),
    [SAE] varchar(10),
    [CURR MNBR] varchar(255),
    [AID] varchar(255)
)
CREATE TABLE #merged_products (
    [pID] int,
    [Thickness] decimal(20, 4),
    [Width] decimal(20, 4),
    [Length] decimal(20, 4),
    [Grade] varchar(10),
    [MNumber] varchar(255),
    [Config] varchar(255),
    [AID] varchar(255)
)

INSERT INTO #raw_customer VALUES
(0.299, 48, 100, 'XB0', NULL,       ''),
(0.3,   60, 120, 'XB0', 'M723087',  ''),
(0.25,  48, 140, 'GR1', 'M701283',  '906008314'),
(0.25,  60, 140, 'Y45', NULL,       '008008314'),
(0.125, 72, 205, 'GR7', 'M712390',  '005003468')

INSERT INTO #merged_products VALUES
(1, 0.2990, 48.0000, 100.0000, 'XB0', NULL,     'Stock', ''),
(2, 0.3000, 60.0000, 120.0000, 'XB0', NULL,     'Stock', ''),
(3, 0.2500, 48.0000, 140.0000, 'GR1', 'M701283',    'Stock', ''),
(4, 0.2500, 60.0000, 140.0000, 'Y45', NULL,     'Raced', ''),
(5, 0.1250, 72.0000, 205.0000, 'GR7', 'M712390',    'Raced', '900751488; 006008314; '),
(6, 0.1250, 72.0000, 205.0000, 'GR7', 'M712390',    'Raced', '005003468; 006025951; 006022051')


SELECT
    mp.[pID],
    r.[DECIMAL],    mp.[Thickness],
    r.[WIDTH],      mp.[Width],
    r.[LENGTH],     mp.[Length],
    r.[SAE],        mp.[Grade],
    mp.[Config],    
    r.[CURR MNBR],  mp.[MNumber],
    r.[AID],        mp.[AID]
  FROM #raw_customer r
  LEFT JOIN #merged_products mp ON
    CAST(r.[DECIMAL] AS decimal(20,4))  = CAST(mp.[Thickness] AS decimal(20,4)) AND
    CAST(r.[WIDTH] AS decimal(20,4))    = CAST(mp.[Width] AS decimal(20,4)) AND
    CAST(r.[LENGTH] AS decimal(20,4))   = CAST(mp.[Length] AS decimal(20,4)) AND
    (
        (
            r.[CURR MNBR] IS NULL AND mp.[Config] = 'Stock'
        ) OR (
            r.[CURR MNBR] IS NOT NULL AND r.[CURR MNBR] IN ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(mp.[MNumber],','))
        )
    ) AND
    r.[AID] = (
    CASE
        WHEN r.[AID] IN ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(mp.[AID],',') ) THEN ( SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(mp.[AID],',') )
        ELSE '' -- r.[AID] would need to match any value if not found in mp.[AID].  r.[AID] does have NULL values
    END ) AND
    r.[SAE] = mp.[Grade]
  GROUP BY
    mp.[pID], mp.[Thickness], mp.[Width], mp.[Length], mp.[Grade], mp.[MNumber], mp.[Config], mp.[AID], 
    r.[DECIMAL], r.[WIDTH], r.[LENGTH], r.[SAE], r.[CURR MNBR], r.[AID]
ORDER BY r.[AID]
```

This is the results that I'm looking for, in particular the last one which where it only selects #6 from #5 or #6

```
|pID    |DECIMAL|Thickness|WIDTH|Width   |LENGTH| Length    |SAE    |Grade  |Config  |CURR MNBR |MNumber  |AID          |AID
|1      | 0.299 |   0.2990| 48  | 48.0000| 100  | 100.0000  | 'XB0' | 'XB0' | 'Stock'|NULL      |NULL     | ''          |NULL|
|2      | 0.3   |   0.3000| 60  | 60.0000| 120  | 120.0000  | 'XB0' | 'XB0' | 'Stock'|'M723087' |NULL     | ''          |NULL|
|3      | 0.25  |   0.2500| 48  | 48.0000| 140  | 140.0000  | 'GR1' | 'GR1' | 'Stock'|'M701283' |'M701283'| '906008314' |NULL|
|4      | 0.25  |   0.2500| 60  | 60.0000| 140  | 140.0000  | 'Y45' | 'Y45' | 'Raced'|NULL      |NULL     | '008008314' |NULL|
|6      | 0.125 |   0.1250| 72  | 72.0000| 205  | 205.0000  | 'GR7' | 'GR7' | 'Raced'|'M712390' |'M712390'| '005003468' |'005003468; 006025951; 006022051'|
```

Comment: You shouldn't store values in comma-separated strings (thus violating the first normal form). What to do when a #raw_customer has no row in #merged_products matching the measures? What to do when a #raw_customer has several rows in #merged_products matching the measures, but none of them matches its AID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you break-up the concatenated aid into rows and at the same time calculate a row number so that you avoid repitition in the results e.g.

```
SELECT p.pID,Thickness,Width,Length,Grade,MNumber,Config, aid as xaid
    , trim(s.value) AS AID
    , coalesce(trim(nullif(s.value,' ')),'999999999')
    , row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY MNumber, Thickness, Width, Length, Grade 
        ORDER BY coalesce(trim(nullif(s.value,' ')),'999999999') ASC
        ) AS rn
FROM #merged_products AS p
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(case when p.aid <> ' ' then concat(';',p.AID) end, ';')  AS s
```

| pID | Thickness | Width | Length | Grade | MNumber | Config | xaid | AID | (No column name) | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0.2500 | 60.0000 | 140.0000 | Y45 | *null* | Raced |  | *null* | 999999999 | 1 |
| 1 | 0.2990 | 48.0000 | 100.0000 | XB0 | *null* | Stock |  | *null* | 999999999 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.3000 | 60.0000 | 120.0000 | XB0 | *null* | Stock |  | *null* | 999999999 | 1 |
| 3 | 0.2500 | 48.0000 | 140.0000 | GR1 | M701283 | Stock |  | *null* | 999999999 | 1 |
| 6 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 005003468; 006025951; 006022051 | 005003468 | 005003468 | 1 |
| 5 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 900751488; 006008314; | 006008314 | 006008314 | 2 |
| 6 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 005003468; 006025951; 006022051 | 006022051 | 006022051 | 3 |
| 6 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 005003468; 006025951; 006022051 | 006025951 | 006025951 | 4 |
| 5 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 900751488; 006008314; | 900751488 | 900751488 | 5 |
| 5 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 900751488; 006008314; |  | 999999999 | 6 |
| 6 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 005003468; 006025951; 006022051 |  | 999999999 | 7 |
| 5 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | M712390 | Raced | 900751488; 006008314; |  | 999999999 | 8 |

Once we have this result we can use it as a subquery in an overall simplified query:

```
SELECT mp.[pID]
    , r.[DECIMAL]
    , mp.[Thickness]
    , r.[WIDTH]
    , mp.[Width]
    , r.[LENGTH]
    , mp.[Length]
    , r.[SAE]
    , mp.[Grade]
    , mp.[Config]
    , r.[CURR MNBR]
    , mp.[MNumber]
    , r.[AID]
    , mp.[AID]
FROM #raw_customer r
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
          p.pID,Thickness, Width, Length, Grade, MNumber, Config, aid
        , trim(s.value) AS XAID
        , row_number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY MNumber, Thickness, Width, Length, Grade 
            ORDER BY coalesce(trim(nullif(s.value,' ')),'999999999') ASC
            ) AS rn
    FROM #merged_products AS p
    OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(case when p.aid <> ' ' then concat(';',p.AID) end, ';')  AS s
    ) mp ON r.[DECIMAL] = mp.[Thickness]
    AND r.[WIDTH] = mp.[Width]
    AND r.[LENGTH] = mp.[Length]
```

| pID | DECIMAL | Thickness | WIDTH | Width | LENGTH | Length | SAE | Grade | Config | CURR MNBR | MNumber | AID | AID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.2990 | 0.2990 | 48.0000 | 48.0000 | 100.0000 | 100.0000 | XB0 | XB0 | Stock | *null* | *null* |  |  |
| 2 | 0.3000 | 0.3000 | 60.0000 | 60.0000 | 120.0000 | 120.0000 | XB0 | XB0 | Stock | M723087 | *null* |  |  |
| 3 | 0.2500 | 0.2500 | 48.0000 | 48.0000 | 140.0000 | 140.0000 | GR1 | GR1 | Stock | M701283 | M701283 | 906008314 |  |
| 4 | 0.2500 | 0.2500 | 60.0000 | 60.0000 | 140.0000 | 140.0000 | Y45 | Y45 | Raced | *null* | *null* | 008008314 |  |
| 6 | 0.1250 | 0.1250 | 72.0000 | 72.0000 | 205.0000 | 205.0000 | GR7 | GR7 | Raced | M712390 | M712390 | 005003468 | 005003468; 006025951; 006022051 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/68IG9an1)

Comment: Your code works for the example, but doesn't work right for my actual data.  Not sure why as I used the specific one I am having issues with for the sample.  It got me going in the right direction, thank you!